# Do you need a certain apartment to do a heist in GTA Online?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Do you need a certain apartment to do a heist in GTA Online or can it be any apartment?

Comment: I think this questions needs clarification. What do you mean with "heists"? Robbing other players or unlocking missions that might require planning just like in the singleplayer?

Answer (score 3):

it is definitely known. you need a high end apartment with a planning room. $200k and up should be fine as all the high end apartments are identical inside. once heists are enabled you will be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

(Note: my experience is on PC)

(Note2: this applies to the heists added in the heists update, that is Fleeca, Prison break, Humane Raid, Series A, and Pacific Standard. The doomsday and casino heists have their own property requirements).

According to the message you get from Lester you need a "high end apartment". This will give you a "heist planning room". You then have to wait for an invite from Lester to host each heist.

You do not need a to own a "high end apartment" to join a heist as a crew member through an invite. I think you do need one to use the "quick join heist" feature. The host's high end apartment acts as a base for the heist.

What I'm not sure on is what properties count as "high end apartments". I know when I first tried this I bought the cheapest property in the "high end" category on dynasty8 and it turned out to be a standalone garage without a heist planning room. Scrolling down the list of "high end" properties sorted by price until I reached something described as an "apartment" and buying that gave me a suitable property.

I have definitely experienced heists hosted in properties with multiple different interiors. I have also seen heists hosted in properties that were houses rather than apartments. I don't know if this is specific to the "next gen" versions of the game though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not known yet whether you will need a certain type of apartment as heists haven't been added yet, however you absolutely will need an apartment of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Heists will be part of a free DLC pack [as confirmed by Rockstar](http://www.dlcentral.com/xbox360/xbox360news/gta-online-first-dlc-revealed-will-be-released-for-free-details/). You will need to spend at least 200k to get a luxurious enough pad with a planning board.

All luxury apartments have the same interior and garage, so you may not want to bother getting the most expensive ones. There is no point unless you want a slightly better view of Los Santos.

Answer (score 0):

In the retail website (Dynasty8) there are three types of apartments/garages. There is low end, medium end, and high end. You need to buy a **high end** apartment to have a heist planning room. From there, you can start heists.

Answer (score -1):

To do a heist it can be in any apartment that is being rented to a NPC civilian. Some apartments are unrented and all you do is just break in. Nothing really interesting to do when you realize there's nothing to steal.